# Spark BigQuery Connector: BaseEncoding$DecodingException: Unrecognized character: 0xa

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to save a spark dataframe to a BigQuery table from an AWS EMR cluster. I am using the [spark-bigquery-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector#how-do-i-authenticate-outside-gce--dataproc) to do this. I have encoded my gcloud credentials service json file to Base64 from the command-line and am simply pasting the string for the `credentials` options. This does not work however, and causes the encoding error below. I know my json file is correct because I use it while running my script locally. What is causing this issue?

GCLOUD Service Credentials JSON File Structure

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "<MY_PROJECT_NAME>",
  "private_key_id": "<PRIVATE_KEY_ID>",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----<LONG LIST OF CHARS>-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "service@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "<CLIENT_ID>",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/<service>%40<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Spark Code

```
df \
        .drop(*cols_to_drop) \
        .write \
        .format("bigquery") \
        .option("temporaryGcsBucket", "emr_spark") \
        .option("credentials", "<LONG_BASE64_STRING>") \
        .option("project", "<MY_PROJECT_NAME>") \
        .option("parentProject", "<MY_PROJECT_NAME>") \
        .option("table", "<MY_PROJECT_NAME>:dataset.table") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .save()
```

Error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o137.save.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$DecodingException: Unrecognized character: 0xa
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.decode(BaseEncoding.java:219)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.util.Base64.decodeBase64(Base64.java:104)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryOptions.createCredentials(SparkBigQueryOptions.scala:47)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider$.createBigQuery(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:125)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider$$anonfun$getOrCreateBigQuery$1.apply(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:107)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider$$anonfun$getOrCreateBigQuery$1.apply(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:107)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.getOrCreateBigQuery(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:107)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelation(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$DecodingException: Unrecognized character: 0xa
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$Alphabet.decode(BaseEncoding.java:490)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$Base64Encoding.decodeTo(BaseEncoding.java:974)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.decodeChecked(BaseEncoding.java:233)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.decode(BaseEncoding.java:217)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: How did you encode json file? Recomended way is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/base64-encoding#encoding_content_as_base64), like : `base64 [SOURCE_FILE] -w 0 > [ENCODED_FILE]`.

Comment: @mk_sta I used the openssl to encode the file: `openssl base64 -in <infile> -out <outfile>`. I'll see if using the other method you linked will help, although I am not sure why one method of base64 encoding should fail. One other thing is when I decoded my base64, it was the same json file.

Comment: @mk_sta Using the method in the google link also causes the same encoding error

Comment: @Megan just to make sure - have you tried to decode the base64 and got the exact content of the original file?

Comment: @DavidRabinowitz  Yes I have decoded my base64 and gotten the same content back. I was wondering if something was wrong with my JSON file? Either the formatting or the information it contained? I have also checked it multiple times in online base64 validators.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the issue arises because the connector expects string input, but the Base64 encoding generates a bytes object. So simply utf-8 decoding the Base64 encoded bytes solved my DecodingException.

```
import json
import base64
creds = JSON credentials

# Dump json to str. Encode to utf-8 to get bytes. Encode bytes to Base64 bytes. 
# Decode bytes to get a string
creds64 = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(creds).encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue was how the string was represented in my python script.

**Representing the string in multiple lines caused the encoding error:**

```
credentials="""
ewogICJ0eXBlIjogInNlcnZpY2VfYWNjb3VudCIsCiAgInByb2plY3RfaWQiOiAiPE1ZX1BST0pFQ1RfTkFNRT4iL
AogICJwcml2YXRlX2tleV9pZCI6ICI8UFJJVkFURV9LRVlfSUQ+IiwKICAicHJpdmF0ZV9rZXkiOiAiLS0tLS1CRU
dJTiBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tPExPTkcgTElTVCBPRiBDSEFSUz4tLS0tLUVORCBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tXG4
iLAogICJjbGllbnRfZW1haWwiOiAic2VydmljZUBwcm9qZWN0LmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIiwKICAi
Y2xpZW50X2lkIjogIjxDTElFTlRfSUQ+IiwKICAiYXV0aF91cmkiOiAiaHR0cHM6Ly9hY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY
29tL28vb2F1dGgyL2F1dGgiLAogICJ0b2tlbl91cmkiOiAiaHR0cHM6Ly9vYXV0aDIuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb20vdG
9rZW4iLAogICJhdXRoX3Byb3ZpZGVyX3g1MDlfY2VydF91cmwiOiAiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb20
vb2F1dGgyL3YxL2NlcnRzIiwKICAiY2xpZW50X3g1MDlfY2VydF91cmwiOiAiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlYXBp
cy5jb20vcm9ib3QvdjEvbWV0YWRhdGEveDUwOS88c2VydmljZT4lNDA8cHJvamVjdD4uaWFtLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb
3VudC5jb20iCn0=
"""
```

**Representing the string in one line fixed my issue:**

```
credentials="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"
```

*As mentioned in comments, you can also use the backslash at the end of each line as well*

Comment: Another way to handle it might be to write a backslash at the end of each line, then Python will ignore the newlines and paste the lines together.